# how do you fix this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I need some help figuring out how to get left and right fit into h. Thank you!

what i am trying to do is to get Sprites to fall diagonally down left and right Randomly.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Games\Desktop\website\code\wah.py", line 288, in <module>

'right': random.randint(bmin, bmax),

File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 213, in randint

return self.randrange(a, b+1)

File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 191, in randrange

raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))

ValueError: empty range for randrange() (-1,-5, -4)
```

and this is my code:

```
        newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                    'speed': random.randint(baddieminspeed, baddiemaxspeed),
                    'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                     'left': random.randint(baddiemin, baddiemax),
                     'right': random.randint(bmin, bmax),
                     'h': random.randint(b['left'], b['right'])
                    }
```

Comment: What error? I can see some code, but no error description.

Comment: i added the error just now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
random.randint(bmin, bmax)
```

Using [`randint(a, b)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) requires that `a <= b`.

However, in your case, `bmin` is `-1` and `bmax` is `-5`, so the relation isn’t true: `-1 <= -5` is false.

You need to exchange the values, so `bmin` contains the actual smaller number.